# Installing libxcb - No package 'xcb-proto' found

Tags: linux

I'm attempting to install Xorg on linux (CentOS 6.6) by following "Beyond Linux From Scratch"(http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/cvs/x/xorg7.html), and had an issue while installing libxcb-1.12 with:

```
./configure $XORG_CONFIG --enable-xinput \
--without-doxygen --docdir='${datadir}'/doc/libxcb-1.12
```

where:

```
$XORG_CONFIG="--prefix=/usr --sysconfdir=/etc --localstatedir=/var --disable-static"
```

And I got the error:

```
...
checking for XCBPROTO... no
configure: error: Package requirements (xcb-proto >= 1.12) were not met:

No package 'xcb-proto' found

Consider adjusting the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable if you
installed software in a non-standard prefix.

Alternatively, you may set the environment variables XCBPROTO_CFLAGS
and XCBPROTO_LIBS to avoid the need to call pkg-config.
See the pkg-config man page for more details.
```

I've already installed below by following the instruction from the website:

- util-macros-1.19.0
- Xorg Protocol Headers
- linXau-1.0.8
- libXdmcp-1.1.2
- xcb-proto-1.12

It seemed there were no issues with xcb-proto installation, but not 100% sure.
I can find some files in `/usr/share/xcb` and `/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/xcbgen` after the installation.

Comment: » No package 'xcb-proto' found « : Means no `/usr/lib(64)/pkgconfig/xcb-proto.pc`

Comment: Thanks. Solved by `export PKG_CONFIG_PATH="/usr/lib/pkgconfig"`. I found `xcb-proto.pc` there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> » No package 'xcb-proto' found «

Means no `/usr/lib(64)/pkgconfig/xcb-proto.pc`

Comment: Thanks. Solved by `export PKG_CONFIG_PATH="/usr/lib/pkgconfig"`. I found `xcb-proto.pc` there.